# Find the mean magnitude of values inside unit circle

Tags: python, performance, error-handling, mathematics

I'm fairly new to Python and am exploring how to fix functions and make code 'more effective and readable'. As a first step, I would want to try to make shorter snippets of code here - for example by dividing it into more functions.

I would also appreciate further improvements regarding possible errors I might stumble upon.

No need for imports.

The code is supposed to take values from a batch on a x- and y-position in the unit circle.
Example input:

```
1, 0.1, 0.1, 10 
1, 0.2, 0.2, 15
2, 1.2, 1.2, 20
2, 0.5, 0.5, 25
```

Several values can be used in a batch.  If x² + y² > 1, it will not take that value into account when calculating the average of a batch. If no values in a batch are used, no average is calculated (avoiding division by zero).

```
def a():
    while True:
        data = dict()  # Or data = {} 
        try:
            filename = input('Which data file? ') 
            with open(filename, 'r') as h:  
                for line in h:  
                    try:
                        four_vals = line.split(',')  
                        batch = four_vals[0]  
                        if not batch in data:  
                            data[batch] = []  
                        data[batch] += [  
                            (float(four_vals[1]), float(four_vals[2]), float(four_vals[3]))]  
                    except ValueError: 
                        print('Some data are not integers in batch',batch,", line", line,"\nThose values are not taken into account\n" )
        except IOError: 
            print('No such file or directory was found, the written file can not be opened.'"\n"'Look through misspellings or that the written file is actually in the pathway.')
            continue
        return data


def b(): 
    data = a()
    data = dict(sorted(data.items()))
    return data


def c():
    data = b()
    for batch, sample in data.items():
        try: #len(sample) > 0: 
            n = 0  # antal prov startar på 0
            x_sum = 0  # summan startar på 0
            for (x, y, val) in sample:  
                circle = x ** 2 + y ** 2
                if circle <= 1:  
                    x_sum += val  
                    n += 1  
                else:
                    print(batch,"\t","Outside of the unit circle,", circle,">1")
            average = x_sum / n  
            print(batch, "\t", average)
        except ZeroDivisionError: 
            print(batch, "\tNo data")
```

Comment: Some clarification of the input file format would be good; I can derive it from the code, but it's not at all obvious.

Answer (score 6):

### Some good stuff:

- You're using error-specific `except` clauses.
- You're using `where` blocks.

### Items you can improve:

- Use a `main` method. See [here](https://www.guru99.com/learn-python-main-function-with-examples-understand-main.html) for an example; in particular Example 2.
- Don't nest function *definitions* unnecessarily. Instead of calling `c`, which calls `b` which calls `a`, pass their return values to each other:

  ```py
  def main():
    c(b(a()))
  ```
- Give your functions better names. Give-or-take the cost of verbosity, a function's name should tell you clearly what it does. When in doubt, give everything a clear whole-word name.
- What's the point of `b`? If sorting the batches is important, leave a comment that explains why.
- Consider learning [comprehensions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comprehensions-in-python/).
- Until you learn `class`es and `dataclass`es (or `NamedTuple`s), you can just use tuples to represent sequences of known length. This encodes your assumptions in the structure of the code.
- Not that I like mutating values, but `list` has an `append` method; you don't have to say `+=[item]`. (It's more efficient too.)
  More broadly, it's always a good investment to read the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) for whatever tools you're using.
- Separate your user-input loop from your file-parsing process. This will probably require you to nest one function definition inside another:

  ```py
  def a():
      while True:
          try:
              filename = input('Which data file? ') 
              with open(filename, 'r') as h:
                  return parse_file(h)
          except IOError: 
              print('No such file or directory was found, the written file can not be opened.'"\n"'Look through misspellings or that the written file is actually in the pathway.')

  def parse_line(line):
      batch, x, y, val = line.split(',')  # may raise if there's not the right number!
      return batch, tuple(float(i)  # should these all be floats? should batch be a string?
                          for i in (x, y, val))

  def parse_file(open_handle):
      data = {}
      for line in open_handle:
          try:
              batch, triple = parse_line(line)
              data.setdefault(batch, []).append(triple)
          except ValueError: 
              print('Some data are not integers in batch',batch,", line", line,"\nThose values are not taken into account\n" )  
      return data
  ```
- Try to have all your validation in one place:

  ```py
  def parse_line(line):
      b_, x_, y_, v_ = line.split(',')
      batch, x, y, val = strip(b_), float(x_), float(y_), int(v_)
      if (x**2) + (y**2) <= 1:
          return batch, (x, y, val)
      else:
          raise ValueError("How can you get the correct message to print out?")
  ```
- If you do all your validation early, do you still need the `try... except ZeroDivisionError`? I have mixed feelings. On the one hand, it looks like it will no longer be able to happen. On the other, I don't want to encourage you to remove a failsafe.
- Right now `c` has so many layers of indentation, maybe you should break out a separate function for handling a single batch. On the other hand, you can reduce the complexity by using more off-the-shelf stuff:

  ```py
  def c(data):
      for batch, samples in data.items():
          n = len(samples)
          if n:
              total = sum(val for (x, y, val) in samples)
              average = total / n  
              print(batch, "\t", average)
  ```